# How to Duplicate a Small Table To All Amps?

Tags: sql, database, data-structures, teradata

I have a Small Table in a Teradata Database that consists of 30 rows and 9 columns.

How do I **duplicate** the Small Table across all amps?

*Note: this is the opposite of what one usually wants to do with a Large Table, distribute the rows evenly*

Comment: please provide some specifics. Thank you.

Comment: you may want to look into teradata mirroring aka fallback, this way each row is stored twice

Comment: Teradata does not currently support storing data duplicated (at rest) across AMPs. If you collect statistics on the table, the optimizer will dynamically duplicate it during query processing. You can reduce the cost of duplication by placing it in a single-AMP hash map (for TD16.10+) or by creating an artificial Primary Index with a constant value and then qualifying on that index value (perhaps in a view). That way it's a one-AMP read and broadcast operation.

Comment: To add to Fred's comment, if you look at the explain plan you will see the optimizer doing this,  I think it's something like `we do an all-amps retrieve from <small table>...which is duplicated on all amps`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not "duplicate" the same table content across all amps. You can try to store all rows from the table to one AMP through unevenly distributed rows. So if I understand the request you want all rows from your small table to be stored on one amp only. 
If so, you can create a column that has the same value for all rows(if you don't already have this). You can make it INTEGER column in order to use less space. Then you have to make this column primary index of the table and your actual keys you can make them as secondary keys.
You can check how the rows are stored on the amps true the code below.

```
SELECT
TABLENAME
,VPROC AS NUM_AMP
,CAST(SUM(CURRENTPERM)/(1024*1024*1024) AS DECIMAL(18,5)) AS USEDSPACE_IN_GB
FROM DBC.TABLESIZEV
WHERE UPPER(DATABASENAME) = UPPER('databasename') AND UPPER(TABLENAME) = UPPER('tablename')
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1;
```

or

```
SELECT
HASHAMP(HASHBUCKET(HASHROW(primary_index_columns))) AS "AMP"
,COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM databasename.tablename
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```